# Displaying facebook news feed in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I display only the news feed from facebook on the device?  Is this possible with a FB dialog?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537144/facebook-news-feed-reader-on-android

Answer (score 0):

No.  You have to retrieve the feed from the graph and then render it in a table or whatever control you would like to use.

Comment: Retrieve feed from the graph... can u please elaborate that