# Facebook news feed reader on android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying for a facebook integration on my android application.

My requirement is to read each news feed as and when it comes, and to display it using a toast.

All the sample application I see on net are based on the web GUI. 
Can anyone help me with a sample code or hint to read the updates into a variable/string in my application?

Regards,
Dhanesh

Comment: means you want facebook newsfeed ...?

Comment: Did u get the answer for this question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using this after login in facebook dialog..

```
     Facebook fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
     String newsfeed=fb.request("me/home"); 
     System.out.println(newsfeed);
```

for get user news feed....

Comment: Thanks a lot CapDroid. This was exactly the code snippet I was looking for. I missed the request method, and was in search for a method named 'newsfeed' :) .. .Anyways thanks a lot for the help... btw, how can I parse the exact "news/status" from this whole string?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that won't work anymore: Operation "Developer Love"  http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/417/ resulted in enforcing auth token for each request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's easiest done using Facebook Android SDK (you need permission for your application to access someone's news feed);

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

And Graph API documentation is a good read too;

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Maybe there's some better examples but I found those documents rather complete while I was dealing with Facebook accessing.

Comment: Thanks harism, I have got a sample application to post to wall. This application uses DialogListener. I dont want to use such a view in my app. My requirement is to read each updates i receive in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Facebook API at http://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: I had checked that and got the facebook sdk to be used. Still I am unable to find a method to read the normal "news feed" of facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at facebook's owns api. [Mobile Apps](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android). If they don't have a solution on getting new news, then theres probably no clean api to get news an you have to turn to a scrape api or write your own scrape functions.